# Simple AES encryption using WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, aes

I need to do simple single-block AES encryption / decryption in my Qt / C++ application. This is a "keep the honest people honest" implementation, so just a basic `encrypt(key, data)` is necessary--I'm not worried about initialization vectors, etc. My input and key will always be exactly 16 bytes.

I'd *really* like to avoid another dependency to compile / link / ship with my application, so I'm trying to use what's available on each platform. On the Mac, this was a one-liner to `CCCrypt`. On Windows, I'm getting lost in the API from `WinCrypt.h`. Their example of encrypting a file is almost 600 lines long. *Seriously?*

I'm looking at `CryptEncrypt`, but I'm falling down the rabbit hole of dependencies you have to create before you can call that.

Can anyone provide a simple example of doing AES encryption using the Windows API? Surely there's a way to do this in a line or two. Assume you already have a 128-bit key and 128-bits of data to encrypt.

Comment: I can't provide a simple WinApi example (because one may not exist as you noted), but have you looked into OpenSSL?  I've used it in several projects and it's pretty straightforward.  I know you don't want to add another dependency, but it may end up being a simpler solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the best I've been able to come up with. Suggestions for improvement are welcome!

```
static void encrypt(const QByteArray &data,
                    const QByteArray &key,
                    QByteArray *encrypted) {
  // Create the crypto provider context.
  HCRYPTPROV hProvider = NULL;
  if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProvider,
                           NULL,  // pszContainer = no named container
                           NULL,  // pszProvider = default provider
                           PROV_RSA_AES,
                           CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Unable to create crypto provider context.");
  }

  // Construct the blob necessary for the key generation.
  AesBlob128 aes_blob;
  aes_blob.header.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
  aes_blob.header.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
  aes_blob.header.reserved = 0;
  aes_blob.header.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_128;
  aes_blob.key_length = kAesBytes128;
  memcpy(aes_blob.key_bytes, key.constData(), kAesBytes128);

  // Create the crypto key struct that Windows needs.
  HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;
  if (!CryptImportKey(hProvider,
                      reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&aes_blob),
                      sizeof(AesBlob128),
                      NULL,  // hPubKey = not encrypted
                      0,     // dwFlags
                      &hKey)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Unable to create crypto key.");
  }

  // The CryptEncrypt method uses the *same* buffer for both the input and
  // output (!), so we copy the data to be encrypted into the output array.
  // Also, for some reason, the AES-128 block cipher on Windows requires twice
  // the block size in the output buffer. So we resize it to that length and
  // then chop off the excess after we are done.
  encrypted->clear();
  encrypted->append(data);
  encrypted->resize(kAesBytes128 * 2);

  // This acts as both the length of bytes to be encoded (on input) and the
  // number of bytes used in the resulting encrypted data (on output).
  DWORD length = kAesBytes128;
  if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey,
                    NULL,  // hHash = no hash
                    true,  // Final
                    0,     // dwFlags
                    reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(encrypted->data()),
                    &length,
                    encrypted->length())) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Encryption failed");
  }

  // See comment above.
  encrypted->chop(length - kAesBytes128);

  CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
  CryptReleaseContext(hProvider, 0);
}
```