# AES-128 encryption using WinCrypt

Tags: c++, c, aes, cryptoapi, wincrypt

I need to encrypt strings under AES-128 for my C/C++ app making use of WinCrypt.

Just for understanding how the whole thing works, I have written a program to encrypt a 16 byte string with a 16 byte AES key (128 bits) but it is not working as expected (and the MSDN examples are not helping).

My main problem is with the call to CryptEncrypt, I may not have clear how to use the parameters:

- *pbData
- *pdwDataLen
- dwBufLen

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#define ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM CALG_AES_128

int main()
{

  HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
  HCRYPTKEY hKey;

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Get the handle to the provider.
if(CryptAcquireContext(
    &hCryptProv, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, //MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV
    PROV_RSA_AES, 
    0))
{
    printf("A cryptographic provider has been acquired. \n");
}
else
{
    printf("Error during CryptAcquireContext!\n");
    exit(1);
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------
//  Create a random session key. 

 if(CryptGenKey(
          hCryptProv, 
          ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM, 
          CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, //KEYLENGTH | CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, 
          &hKey))
 {
         printf("A session key has been created.\n");
 } 
 else
 {
          printf("Error during CryptGenKey.\n"); 
          exit(1);
 }
}

char text_test [] = "abcdabcdabcdabcd";
   DWORD text_len = strlen(text_test);

   printf("PlainText: %s\n",text_test);
   printf("Buf Len: %d\n",text_len);

   if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey,
                    NULL,  // hHash = no hash
                    1,  // Final
                    0,     // dwFlags
                    &text_test, //*pbData
                    &text_len,  //*pdwDataLen
                    32)) {      //dwBufLen
     printf("Encryption failed\n");
   }

   printf("CipherText: %s\n",text_test);
   printf("Len: %d\n",text_len);

   if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey,
                    NULL,  // hHash = no hash
                    1,  // Final
                    0,     // dwFlags
                    &text_test,
                    &text_len)) {
     printf("Decryption failed\n");
   }

   printf("PlainText: %s\n",text_test);
   printf("Len: %d\n",text_len);
.
.
.
CryptDestroyKey(hKey)
.
.
CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0)
.
```

The output in the cmd is:

[image]

Can anyone explain me why the decrypted string is longer and which is the correct use of that three parameters of CryptEncrypt? I set the last value to 32 because after some trial and error that was the only value which made this stuff work. Help please and thank you in advance!

Comment: i thing the rest of decrypted string is the padding

Comment: @zapredelom yes, I think it could be padding, but I do not know how to use correctly the parameters of CryptEncrypt.

Comment: https://github.com/panahiehsancom/AESWinAPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new to crytography too, but this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985744/simple-aes-encryption-using-winapi) might have your solution:

```
  // This acts as both the length of bytes to be encoded (on input) and the
  // number of bytes used in the resulting encrypted data (on output).
  DWORD length = kAesBytes128;
  if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey,
                    NULL,  // hHash = no hash
                    true,  // Final
                    0,     // dwFlags
                    reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(encrypted->data()),
                    &length,
                    encrypted->length())) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Encryption failed");
  }

  // See comment above.
  encrypted->chop(length - kAesBytes128);
```

Or i might have some working from a similar project code using Crypto++

Comment: Thank you but I saw this post before posting my question. In this example I do not understand the parameters *pbData nor dwBufLen. I do not know how to use them in my code.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379924(v=vs.85).aspx is the API doc
`pbData -
A pointer to a buffer that contains the plaintext to be encrypted. The plaintext in this buffer is overwritten with the ciphertext created by this function.`

`dwBufLen - Specifies the total size, in bytes, of the input pbData buffer.`

Seems straightforward to me.

Comment: Also, AES is a block cypher, so this restriction applies: `When a block cipher is used, this data length must be a multiple of the block size unless this is the final section of data to be encrypted and the Final parameter is TRUE.`

Answer (score 0):

It's padding. By default, you'll get an equal amount of padding inserted as the bytes you encrypt. Ignore the last 16 bytes. The first 16 bytes are what you want.